# Как в telegram боте подключить новости, время, погоду и т.п.? на python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Как в telegram боте подключить новости, время, погоду и т.п.? Чтобы несколько раз в день приходило уведомление о погоде или новостях? Или если человек спрашивает "сколько время?", то бот отвечал сколько время. Спасибо за ранее! На языке программирования python.

Comment: Создание функции с парсингом метеорологических сайтов - для погоды. Парсинг новостных сайтов исходя из тематики новостей.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Синоптических сайтов. Метеоролог тот кто изучает погоду, синоптик - тот кто предсказывает. Ошиблась.

Comment: @Tanya только не парсинг, а предпочтительно готовое API использовать, если есть.